# How to trigger on spesific selectbox change using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to do somthing after user change the selected value, with this code i only 
want to get values from the selected one, and not both of them.

So far i have this:

Issiue with the code is that only the first one triggers.

```
<div class="colname">
    <label for="input">Input</label>                                                            
    <select name="input" class="input">
        <option>Test1</option>
        <option>Test2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="colname">
    <label for="kostnad">Input</label>                                                          
    <select name="input" class="input">
        <option>Test1</option>
        <option>Test2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    $('.input').change(function(){
         var ok = $(this).val();
          if(ok == 1)
            // do that and this

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` inside the `change` event handler of `select`.

Comment: TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fully working snippet

```js
 $('.input').change(function(){
        $("#value").html($(this).val())
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colname">
    <label for="input1">Input</label>                                                            
    <select name="input1" class="input">
        <option value="input1">Test1</option>
        <option value="input2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="colname">
    <label for="kostnad">Input</label>                                                          
    <select name="kostnad" class="input">
        <option value="kostnad1">Test1</option>
        <option value="kostnad2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="colname">
    <label id="value"></label> 
</div>
```

You need to use `$(this).val()`

```
$('.input').on('change',function (){

$(this).val()
//use here

});
```

Ps. The value will depend on `option` values.

```
<option value="option1">option 1<\option>
```

Comment: it will only trigger the first element change, and not the 2,3 and so on.

Comment: i have added the value fields as well, but it wount react on the 2th, 3th and so on.

Comment: @sdfgg45 just posted a working code please mark as correct answer if solved your problem

Comment: @sdfgg45 did it help? please mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.input').on("change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

Note: you have put a `value` attribute in `<option></option>` tag like this

```
<div class="colname">
    <label for="input">Input</label>                                                            
    <select name="input" class="input">
        <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it will only trigger the first element change, and not the 2,3 and so on.

Comment: You have same option and value for all. Change the value of 2 and 3. I think everything will be okay.